# Arithmetical Hierarchy: where to learn it?

Tags: logic, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm studying Peter Smith's "An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems" but got stuck on the subject of arithmetical hierarchy. Given that, I would like to know what are the standard books and papers where people learn it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where/how did you get stuck? that will help us recommend useful sources.

Comment: On chapter 11 Smith's presents what Robinson arithmetic can correctly decide. If I understood, he goes on introducing definitions for the class of sentences that Q can correctly decides and states the importance of one of those class for Gödel's theorems. As it isn't given any general introduction to arithmetical hierarchy, going straighforward definition of delta, sigma and pi classes I feel like as if I'm missing something because I'm not being able to classify by myself what formulas belong to what class. Then I would like some more passed introduction to it.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to note that I'm a master student in Philosophy and haven't received formal training in Mathematics.

Comment: Herbert Enderton, [Computability Theory : An Introduction to Recursion Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=y8n76ztNVlMC&pg=PA103) (2011) up to **Ch.5**.

Answer (score 1):

SOARE, Robert. Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees: A study of Computable Functions and Computably Generated Sets (1987) up to Ch.4.